# fetching json in seperate component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, web-applications, jsx

I've made an application and want to add more components which will use the same json I fetched in "personlist.js", so I don't want to use fetch() in each one, I want to make a separate component that only does fetch, and call it in the other components followed by the mapping function in each of the components, how can make the fetch only component ?

here is my fetch method:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("data.json")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        result => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.results
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        error => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      );
  }
```

and here is a sandbox snippet 
https://codesandbox.io/s/1437lxk433?fontsize=14&moduleview=1

Comment: You can (and should :-) ) make your runnable examples **here**, on-site, so you don't accidentally leave out important code. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (They should also be [**minimal**](/help/mcve).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing why this would need to be a component, vs. just a function that the other components use.

But if you want it to be a component that other components use, have them pass it the mapping function to use as a prop, and then use that in `componentDidMount` when you get the items back, and render the mapped items in `render`.

---

In a comment you've clarified:

> I am trying to fetch the json once, & I'm not sure whats the best way to do it.

In that case, I wouldn't use a component. I'd put the call in a module and have the module expose the promise:

```
export default const dataPromise = fetch("data.json")
    .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP status " + res.status);
        }
        return res.json();
    });
```

Code using the promise would do so like this:

```
import dataPromise from "./the-module.js";
// ...
componentDidMount() {
    dataPromise.then(
        data => {
            // ...use the data...
        },
        error => {
            // ...set error state...
        }
    );
}
```

The data is fetched once, on module load, and then each component can use it. It's important that the modules treat the data as read-only. (You might want to have the module export a function that makes a defensive copy.)

Comment: I am trying to fetch the json once, & I'm not sure whats the best way to do it.

Comment: Hello @t-j-crowder, I have an issue on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54917627/product-properties-from-nested-json-reactjs ,  would be of great help if you can give your comment on it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer you're looking for.

fetchDataFunc.js

```
export default () => fetch("data.json").then(res => res.json())
```

Component.js

```
import fetchDataFunc from './fetchDataFunc.'

class Component {
  state = {
    // Whatever that state is
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetchFunc()
      .then(res => setState({ 
        // whatever state you want to set
      }) 
      .catch(err => // handle error)
  }
}
```

Component2.js

```
import fetchDataFunc from './fetchDataFunc.'

class Component2 {
  state = {
    // Whatever that state is
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetchFunc()
      .then(res => setState({ 
        // whatever state you want to set
      }) 
      .catch(err => // handle error)
  }
}
```

You could also have a HOC that does fetches the data once and share it across different components.

Comment: I've done it using the fetchDataFunc.js and it fetched twice, can you explain to me how can I fetch it once in a parent-child just like what you mentioned?